# How does server locate GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) registration IDs

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am trying to write an application which notifies a cellphone using GCM. I was able to implement basic functionality, but there is one question I'm still unsure of

As I understand, the flow goes like this:

1. Device start up
2. Device registers, obtains registration id
3. Server gets the knowledge of registration id on device
4. Server is using it's API key + registration id to send payload to device
5. Device receives payload.

One thing which is unclear to me is: what is a proper methodology to implement step #3?

I could not find any way to obtain a list of registered devices. Lets imagine, I am using GCM for a purpose of posting to a known device, and I could email that ID to myself and then register it on the server manually. But as I understand, it expires.

So, it there an expectation that I have to keep re-registering and somehow notifying server every time it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your app on device must send registration ID to your server application in order for server to be able to send GCM messages. See third point in [Enabling GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#push-process).

Comment: So, there is no GCM based channel for device to supply ID to the server, is there? Must run some other service for that to happen? It just strikes me as failure to think through such an important logistics part

Comment: This is by design. GCM is used by many apps. When device app registers and gets ID, how would GCM know to which server app to send IDs? There could be some shared secret, but this would be highly hackable. iOS uses the same scheme for it's notifications.